# Analyzing Insertion Behavior in a Randomized Hash Table

Tags: hash, probability

The following problem of my is from final exam for my online course last year; I couldn't have the time to do it, so I want to check whether my answer is correct;

Q5) Given an (entirely) random hash function $h : S \times \mathbb{N} \to [p]$, where $p$ is the number of blocks in the hash table of size $p = 2q$, we require that one cell of the hash table contains at most one element of $\Sigma \subset S$, and we insert a new element $s \in \Sigma$ by first checking whether $h(s, 1)$ is occupied; if it isn't, insert $s$ there, and if not, keep checking $h(s, 2)$, $h(s, 3)$, etc until we find the first number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ to try so that $h(s, n)$ is not occupied, and then we can place $s$ in that entry. Answer these:

- Given a new $s$, what is $n$ (in expectation) so that if we have already placed $q$ items in the hash table, $s$ is placed in the entry $h(s, n)$.
- Exhibit an $\Omega$-type lower bound on the probability that $n \geq 0.1\log{q}$.
- Now define $h(s, j+1) = (h(s, j)\ \mathrm{mod}\, p) + 1$. So the first attempt to insert $s$, $h(s, 1)$ is random, but all of the next places to examine follow right after up to a circular repeating pattern. Show that $n$ is $O(1)$ in expectation. (Hint: The probability that any interval $[i:i+k)$ is a block or all full is at most $2^{O(k)}$ for $k \geq 20$.)

Here are my attempts:

1. The probability that a given cell is occupied is $\frac{q}{p} = \frac{q}{2q} = \frac{1}{2}$. The expected value of $n$ can be computed as the sum of the probabilities of finding the first empty cell at each trial. This follows a geometric distribution with success probability $\frac{1}{2}$, giving an expected value of $n = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2$.
2. Note that as $n$ increases, the probability of not finding an empty slot decreases exponentially. Specifically, the probability of not finding an empty slot after $0.1\log{q}$ attempts is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0.1\log{q}} = q^{-0.1\log{2}}$. This gives a lower bound of $\Omega(q^{-0.1\log{2}})$.
3. In the modified scenario, the hash function creates a deterministic sequence post the first random placement. To show that $n$ is $O(1)$, we consider any interval $[i:i+k)$. The probability that this interval is completely occupied is the probability that all $k$ cells are filled. Given that there are already $q$ items, and considering the worst case where all $q$ items are within this interval, the probability is $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^k = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$. For $k \geq 20$, this probability becomes exponentially small, implying that the likelihood of having to check many cells consecutively decreases rapidly, thus ensuring that $n$ remains $O(1)$ in expectation.

---

Are these correct? Is there some mistake somewhere?

Comment: there is some nonstandard terminology here. firstly I think this may not be a question about a cryptographic hash. what does *entirely random* mean? is there a definition you can supply?

Comment: By that I think it means that the hash function is not pseudorandom or otherwise generated via restricted randomness. It's randomly sampled from a family of hash functions.

Comment: is a "block" and a "cell" the same thing?

Comment: Yes they are the same thing!